# Unlock keyring on boot with no desktop?

Tags: gnome-keyring

I have a small linux box I'm toying around with and would like for it to boot without a desktop manager and automatically unlock the keyring. I know that a lot of what I'm doing is against best practices but I'm not protecting anything vital and I just want to see if I can.

I'm using the SetCLIBoot and SetGUIBoot scripts from [this forum post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1715960#p1715960) and I've removed my password from the keychain. When things are configured for me to boot into the GUI, my keychain is unlocked. However this machine won't have a monitor plugged into it 99% of the time and would like to get this working when I set it to boot from CLI. When I run SetCLIBoot and restart into a tty environment, my keyring remains locked and I can't figure out how to unlock it from the command line.

I've tried a few recommendations for [modifying PAM files](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Pam) but never made any progress with that approach.

Being that I have a fresh install of Linux Mint 20, I can't install python-gnomekeyring and run any script with it as it's in xenial but not focal.

I would like to leave my keyring open all the time and not just when I'm SSH'd into it. I have a secure file syncing program who's key is in the keyring and I would like it to sync files locally even when I'm not signed in.